# Clickable slide show with images stored on a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a table called images which consists of alot of images from property images to estate logos...i've written a ruby code to get all property images which works fine...the only problem i have is i want the images to display as a clickable slideshow instead of showing all the images at ones

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Javascript/Flash question than a Rails one. Lightview is a great solution: http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/